# 2 different laptops, 1 home office setup

Tags: laptop, usb, display

My fiancée and I used to have the same HP laptop and shared a single docking station in our home office to connect to a HDMI monitor, keyboard and mouse. I have recently upgraded to a Lenovo X1 Carbon which naturally, doesn't fit the dock any more.

I'm looking at getting a Lenovo USB 3.0 Port Replicator for home and I was wondering if there is some kind of switch I can put in place so we don't have to constantly unplug the monitor etc between the 2 docks because that's probably going to drive us both insane.

Answer (score 8):

The thing you're looking for is a **KVM switch**.

Both computers are plugged into the switch, from there it's plugged into the monitor. You literally switch between the 2 PC's by a switch on the box.

Answer (score 8):

You can get an [HDMI KVM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006H412LO).  This will let you plug one monitor/mouse/keyboard into two computers.

[image: HDMI KVM]

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick replies. Now no need to fight over anything, at least you both know you're right and so do I! Much appreciated :-)